# Using a custom behavior in a custom Polymer/Typescript element throws Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: typescript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I tried to create and use my own behavior according to the [PolymerTS docs](https://github.com/nippur72/PolymerTS#behavior), but an `Uncaught ReferenceError` is thrown (`ListViewBehavior` is not defined).

This is my behavior (`list-view/list-view-behavior.ts`):

```
class ListViewBehavior extends polymer.Base {
  ...
```

and this is how I used it (`asset-list.ts`):

```
/// <reference path="list-view/list-view-behavior.ts"/>
@component('asset-list')
@behavior(ListViewBehavior)
class AssetList extends polymer.Base implements {
  ...
```

If I add the behavior in the same file (`asset-list.ts`), it works.

Comment: Have you tried smth like `import { ListViewBehavior } from 'list-view/list-view-behavior'`?

Comment: That gives a Typescript trans-pile exception: `error TS2306: File '../list-view-behavior.ts' is not a module.`, also if I wrap the class in a module and export it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code. Interestingly, defining the `ListViewBehavior` class without exporting it allows the build to succeed without warnings or errors. The `ReferenceError` occurs at runtime when I try to create the component that uses the behavior.

The fix was to add this import to my component's class file:

```
import 'list-view/list-view-behavior';
```

A cleaner fix that would force a compile error when this situation occurs is to export the behavior's class:

```
// In list-view/list-view-behavior.ts ...
export class ListViewBehavior extends polymer.Base {...}
```

And import it in the component file:

```
// In asset-list.ts ...
import {ListViewBehavior} from 'list-view/list-view-behavior';
```

Comment: This still throws another Runtime Exception: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I suspect I have to add 'require' as a dependency.

Comment: Yeah, that would be your build setup that needs fixing now. I recommend [`polymer-typescript-starter-kit`](https://github.com/tony19/polymer-typescript-starter-kit) (my WIP), which uses SystemJS. It's setup and ready to go. It's actually what I used to verify my answer.

Comment: thanks that helped.
The starter-kit you propose looks promising. I will give it a try if I have some time.

Comment: @pme No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here's what worked finally for me. (When I have time I will give the [`polymer-typescript-starter-kit`](https://github.com/tony19/polymer-typescript-starter-kit) a try, as my solution is not very nice.)

First, I had to create a module:

```
module CMSBehaviors {
   export class ListViewBehavior extends polymer.Base {
   ...
  }
}
```

Then, I could use it directly:

```
@behavior(CMSBehaviors.ListViewBehavior)
```

In the `elements.html`, I added the following:

```
<script src="../bower_components/polymer-ts/polymer-ts.min.js"></script>
<script src="../services/cms-behaviors.js"></script>
```

The `polymer-ts.min.js` is needed, as the behavior extends from `polymer.Base`.